# How to create Windows Server 2003/2008 installation disc

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, compact-disc, reinstall, windows-installation

I have 2 HP Proliant DL 380 G5s that were given to me from a data center. The OS was wiped out of it before it was handed over to me. How would I create my own installation disk so that when the CD ROM is booted, the installation for Windows Server 2003 (or 2008) begins?

The second machine already has Windows Server 2003, but there is no way of knowing the administrator's credentials.

Would I just take an .iso file and burn to a disc?

*Also, the servers will have no keyboard. Just a monitor and a mouse. I will also have a laptop that I have been using to remote into existing servers that are already set up.

Comment: When you purchased windows server, it didn't come with installation media (cd/dvd)?

Comment: All of the other servers I owned were also previously owned (from a data center). They came with the OS in them so purchasing it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding a keyboard to the servers.

Comment: I was then able to select to boot up a disk.